# Embed a view in the body of a node

Tags: views

I want to embed a view into the body of a node on Drupal 7. I've tried the module [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) and that didn't work.

I also saw support from Drupal on inputting PHP code, but I have no idea where to put that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is the [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) module. It allows you to use tokens in the textarea to insert views wherever you'd like.

The UX of having to write out the token may be the biggest downside. I'd personally like to see a WYSIWYG button created to make use of this (similar to [Token Insert Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert_entity)), but it's not too tricky to educate users how to use it by typing the token.

Other negatives could be potential performance and security concerns. As it says in the README.txt:

> ### SECURITY WARNING
>
> This filter is powerful, therefore it should be granted to trusted users only. If you allow this filter to untrusted
>   users, then you have to make sure that EVERY VIEW EVERY DISPLAY
>   (default display also!) has correct views access settings.
>
> ### PERFORMANCE
>
> To display views correctly, Insert view turns off caching for the input formats for which it is enabled. That means every node
>   using this input format will not be cacheable. This can impact site
>   performance. In these cases, it is recommended to create a special
>   input format for use when inserting views.

Comment: That's what I ended up using. The readme.txt did an awful job at explaining how to use the damn thing, but I eventually found out how it worked. It works great and I can pass it off to my clients when my project is over.

Answer (score 7):

When I want to display a View on certain content types, I make use of the functionality offered by the [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module. On the entity's Field Display administration page, you can (like any other field) set the order for outputting the Views' result.

An interesting feature of the [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module is that it allows to pass any token generated from the specific entity to the View as an argument.

Comment: Not sure why "this" answer is not marked as the "accepted" answer ... which I believe does not suffer those security/performance issue as in the accepted answer, right? Anyway: another +1 ...

Comment: Because the question was about putting a view within the body text — not to embed the view within a separate field, or at the top/bottom of the body field. You'll want to do that if you need a particular view to appear between two paragraphs in the body field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [views_embed_views()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7).

```
<?php 
print  views_embed_view('view-name', 'display-name','arguments'); 
?>
```

Put that in your page.tpl.php or other relevant template file in your theme. Use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to find out which template the page is using if needed.

Or you can use the block display on the view and assign your block to the main content region as well.

There are several ways to accomplish this task. I recommend checking out the doc link above and reading the comments for other ways as well.

Comment: So I've seen that "solution" too, but I wanted to know what I do to embed the view in a specific node. For example, if a user views my Resources page, I want them to be able to see the view that I created for that page plus the content that's already on it.

Comment: Make a block display in the views UI and restrict that block to only show on that URL in the block UI. You can place the block in the content region to either show above or below the main content of the page.

Comment: I got that done, but the block still shows on all pages of the content type I'm using.

Comment: In the block settings there is a show on certain pages setting, admin/structure/block then hit configure on the block view and the settings will be on the pages tab

Comment: You can use wildcards or just specify URL like node/1 or the alias of the URL if the radio "Only the listed pages" is set

Comment: Although I can do that, for some reason Drupal still displays the content on other pages. For example, I only want this block to show on the about page ([domain]/about) so I put "about" on the Show Block on Specific Pages with the Only the listed pages button selected. Lo and behold, the block is still displayed on all pages of the content type.

Comment: Did you clear cache after adding these settings, those block settings will hold until cache is cleared.

Comment: Indeed I did. I still see the block on pages it should not appear on.

Comment: Try using the node/3 (with 3 being whatever the node was originally before the alias). To get that go to admin/content (I think that's it but you can edit any piece of content to get the ID) and go to edit the content and use the number (node/3/edit) to replace the 3 in the block settings. Also just a question, you don't happen to have some sort of WYSWYG editor on that field while entering the URLs do you?

Comment: The node/# solution didn't work. I'm still seeing the block displayed on the page it shouldn't be on. Also there is no WYSWYG editor on that field. Just plain text.